# How to code a cycle of options for a button in micropython

Tags: python, button, micropython

I am currently using a Pi Pico with micropython to code a button. This button is supposed to cycle through 11 hard coded options of cities/countries using APIs and gives their time and temperature. The issue is, I have been attempting to find a code that would work for a case like this but the closest I have come to it is buttons with an on/off function.

I only have code for how to code an on/off function for a button, I do not know how to loop or cycle through options. The code I currently have for the button is:

```
button = machine.Pin(12, machine.Pin.IN, machine.Pin.PULL_UP)
while True:
    first = button.value()
    time.sleep(0.01)
    second = button.value()
    if first and not second:
        print('Button pressed!')
    elif not first and second:
        print('Button released!')
```

What should I do to change this to my desired format?

Comment: I recommend that you start by describing in more detail exactly what you want the program to do when you press the button. What does "cycle through 11 hard coded options..." mean? You need to describe the exact behavior more precisely. If this behavior isn't clear in your head that you can describe it clearly to other people, then you will struggle writing code to actually do it. Write an entire paragraph if you need to.

Comment: So, the button needs to cycle through a set list of API data. I have 11 cities for which I will parse an API for their data regarding temperature and timezone. Then this data will be displayed on a screen. I want to code the button so that when someone presses it, the displayed city and its corresponding data will cycle to another one of the 11 cities. In a separate part of the code I parsed the timezone and temperature data from the APIs for the related cities, but now I am unsure how to cycle through those cities using the button. I hope this clears up any confusion

Comment: This is a step in the right directly. Let's work on breaking it down a little more. I assume when you say "cycle through a set of data", you mean for each repeated press of the button. To break it down, what should the button do after ONE press. We also need to think about the state before the button press and how it changes after the button press. It sounds like the screen will show the data for one of the cities. Then what happens after pressing the button once?

Comment: After pressing the button once, the button should change the display on the screen to another city. For example, let's say the default city is Ottawa. So the screen will display Ottawa's temperature and time zone. After pressing the button once, it will change to another city, say Paris and show its temperature and time zone

Comment: Now we are getting somewhere! Notice how we simplified your original question from "how do I cycle through all of the cities when the button is pressed repeatedly?" to "how do I change the displayed city when the button is pressed once?" This seems much simpler to solve and will lead us towards solving the harder problem. With that said, it seems like you need to change the `print('Button released!')` or `print('Button pressed!')` to something. I think the first step is to write some code with the cities. For now I wouldn't worry about the API part. Again, we want to keep it simple.

Comment: I recommend adding two variables `city1` and `city2` with hard coded values. This can be a simple string or a dictionary or a class, depending on what you need to represent the city. Which brings to mind another question...are you able to display city data on the screen for the first city? If not, then you should simplfy this even further to just `city1` and figure out the code to display that data. In fact, you should start with just a string for the city name. Then add the other pieces of data once you get that working.

Comment: I still need to work on getting the display working for the first city, so I will work on that then. Thank you for your help so far! At the moment I can display a string that I enter into the code, so I'm thinking all I need to do is edit the display code so that. After attempting do so, I'm getting the error "OSError: -2" when I try to run it. The line it gives me the error for is the line where I'm trying to get the data from the API.

Comment: As you see in the process I'm leading through you here, a lot of "coding" is actually describing a solution to a problem in words. During this process, breaking the problem down into small parts and solving each individual part will get you a long ways.

Comment: With that said, it sounds like you have a new question with your current error. I recommend that you post a new question here with the current version of the code and describe your problem and desired result in as much detail as you can.

Comment: Okay, I will do so. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The logic of your button checking code doesn't make much sense. It's looking for an on-to-off or off-to-on transition over a 10ms time period. Seems exceedingly unlikely to catch anything.

This might server you better, depending on the rest of your application:

```py
def wait_for_button(button: machine.Pin, sleep_sec = 0.01):
    """
    idles until button is pressed and released; assumes button is configured
    such that a True return value indicates the button is pushed
    """
    while not button.value():
        time.sleep(sleep_sec)
    while button.value():
        time.sleep(sleep_sec)
```

To cycle through a list of options, just use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```py
import itertools

OPTIONS = itertools.cycle(["one", "two", "three"])

current_option = next(OPTIONS)
button = machine.Pin(...)

while True:
    # ...
    wait_for_button(button)
    current_option = next(OPTIONS)
    # ...
```

As was pointed out in the comments, you might not have access to `itertools.cycle`. Here's the functional equivalent pulled from the documentation link above:

```py
def cycle(iterable):
    # cycle('ABCD') --> A B C D A B C D A B C D ...
    saved = []
    for element in iterable:
        yield element
        saved.append(element)
    while saved:
        for element in saved:
              yield element
```

Comment: Good answer for desktop Python, but MicroPython doesn't have `itertools` builtin (and the OP sounds inexperienced so a solution that works with builtin functions might be better than asking them to install additional modules).

Comment: Maybe initialise `options` as a plain list, then after `wait_for_button` do `current_option = options.pop(0); options.append(current_option)` ?